# Maximal elements of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, invariant-subspace

Let $W$ be a subspace of a vector space $V$ and $f$ be an endomorphism of $V$. Show that $$X = \{U \subseteq W\,|\,U \text{ is an $f$-invariant subspace of V}\}$$ with the partial order $\subseteq$ always has a maximal element.

My idea is to find the supremum of $X$, which is the maximal element I want to find, but I am not sure how to approch this problem generally.

Comment: Can you prove that if $U,V \in X$, then $U + V \in X$ ?

Comment: Is this a possible proof? Let $U,V \in X$. $U$ and $V$ are $f$-invariant, thus $f(u) \in U$ and $f(v) \in V$ for $u \in U$ and $v \in V$. $u+v$ is an element of $U+V$, then $f(u) + f(v) = f(u+v)$ is one too, because $f$ is an endomorphism. $U + V$ is $f$-invariant, because $f(u+v) \in U+V$. $U + V$ is a subspace of $V$, that is not very difficult to show.

Comment: consider the union of all of the elements of $X$ it will do the job

Comment: @JulesBesson The fact that this union is still a subspace needs an explanation.

Comment: @Sheep Yes, that is correct. Now try to see how this is linked to the question.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Yes but the comment above suggested why it is. I don't want to spoil, the goal is to give a hint not the answer...

Comment: My idea is $\sum_{U \in X}U$, but I'm not sure if every subset of that sum is also in $X$ itself.